# Beamer themes that look good in 16:9 wide screen

Tags: beamer, themes

Which beamer themes create good looking and functional slides on 16:9 screen? I would like a theme that shows where in document we are, i.e. at least section and maybe even full table of contents.

From what I browsed, most of built-in themes put the section info in the header, if they put it at all.  Those that put this information inn the sidebar (either on left or on the right hand side), like Berkeley or Harbour, unfortunately also use extra wide header -- which makes sense for 4:3 screen, but not for 16:9 one.

Third party themes like Metropolis are usually minimal, and do not provide the information about current section at all.

Comment: I would say infolines themes (Madrid) are quite well suited

Answer (score 2):

> Those that put this information inn the sidebar (either on left or on the right hand side), like Berkeley or Harbour, unfortunately also use extra wide header

You can remove the headline from sidbar themes, like `Berkley`, with the `height=0cm` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[height=0cm]{sidebar}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```